Name of a TV series/drama about a white girl in Japan
A few years ago I watched a series or drama on a website for Asian dramas, recently I watched Massan and it got me thinking about it again.  For the life of me I can't remember the name of it or the website where I watched it. 
So here are the details I do remember:
It's set in the 90's/00's.
I believe A Japanese guy falls in love with a white girl (I believe she is american but could be European), marries her and brings her back to Japan. The father disapproves but mother does approve. The white girl is pregnant and has a son and then the Japanese guy dies. The father says that he'll look after the grandson but she has to leave, says she won't so she leaves and they cut off all communication.
She lives in a small place with her son. She then meets a J-Pop star and becomes friends and then finds out he is actually gay. Her son is bullied but becomes friends with one other boy. The boy's father seems to be a Yakuza boss. The girl and the yakuza boss become friends because of their sons.
